# How to v-if the router-link :to prop when value is null?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuejs3

I have a `router-link` setup where the `path` attribute of `to` prop may sometimes be null. That then causes an error in `vue-router` saying that it cannot find 'indexOf' null.

I would like the `router-link` to only render if there is a `non-null` value available for it to navigate to (obviously). If the value is `null`, then I do not need a link to exist, or, the link could just go to `#` as a placeholder.

This is the `router-link` code:

```
<router-link :to="{ path: Post.urlslug, name: 'PostView', params: {URLSlug: Post.urlslug} }">
   <!-- lots of images and text here with their own v-if statements -->
</router-link>
```

Is it possible to have a conditional statement only on the `:to` binding so that I don't have to do a huge copy and paste of the entire `router-link` block to implement a `v-if` e.g. I'd rather avoid this:

```
 <router-link v-if="Post.urlslug != null && Post.urlslug.length" :to="{ path: Post.urlslug, name: 'PostView', params: {URLSlug: Post.urlslug} }">
       <!-- lots of images and text here with their own v-if statements -->
    </router-link>

 <router-link v-else :to="#"> <!-- <= this doesn't work anyway -->
       <!-- lots of images and text here with their own v-if statements -->
    </router-link>
```

The above code does not work because `#` is not an acceptable value for the `:to` prop. What is the best practice way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:to="#"` is interpreted as '`#` is a variable name'.

Try this.

`<router-link v-else to="#"></router-link>`

Or use `<a>` directly.

`<a v-else href="#"></a>`

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do it with a dynamic component:

```html
<component
  :is="Post.urlslug && Post.urlslug.length > 0 ? 'router-link' : 'a'" 
  :to="Post.urlslug && Post.urlslug.length > 0 ? { path: Post.urlslug, name: 'PostView', params: {URLSlug: Post.urlslug} } : undefined"
  :href="Post.urlslug && Post.urlslug.length > 0 ? undefined : '#'"
>
```

Comment: that is very interesting thank you. but how do I put my content within this component e.g. `<img>` tags etc

Comment: You will put your content in the place of the 3 dots in `<component>...</component>`